# Obtener un valor de un textbox de un DataList

Tags: c#, asp.net

Tengo un DataList en ASP.NET que me trae los productos de la tabla "Productos", por lo que con la instrucción `"Eval"` le asigno el ID del producto:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="idProductoText" runat="server" type="hidden" value='<%# Eval("PRO_ID") %>'></asp:TextBox>
```

Por lo que en mi código C# necesito obtener el valor de ese TextBox por su ID, por ejemplo, un `idProductoText.Text.Trim();` , pero por alguna razón no funciona, ¿Alguna solución?, dejo el DataList completo abajo.

Código para llenar el DataList:

```
public void cargarStockProductos()
        {
            OracleConnection conexion = new OracleConnection(con);
            OracleCommand command = new OracleCommand("MOSTRAR_PRODUCTOS_COMPRAR", conexion);
            command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            command.Parameters.Add("registros", OracleDbType.RefCursor).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
            OracleDataAdapter d = new OracleDataAdapter();
            d.SelectCommand = command;
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            d.Fill(dt);
            DataList1.DataSource = dt;
            DataList1.DataBind();
            conexion.Close();
        }
```

DataList completo en ASP.NET

```
<asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <div class="card mb-6" style="max-width: 1400px">
                            <div class="row g-0">
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <img
                                        src="../../img/sillon.jpg"
                                        class="img-fluid rounded-start"
                                        alt="producto" />
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-lg-5 m-4 form-floating">
                                    <div class="card-body">
                                        <!-- EL ID DEL PRODUCTO ESTÁ OCULTO, SOLO SE USARÁ PARA AGREGAR AL CARRITO -->
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="idProductoText" runat="server" type="hidden" value='<%# Eval("PRO_ID") %>'></asp:TextBox>                
                                        <asp:Label ID="PRO_NOMBRELabel" class="card-title" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("PRO_NOMBRE") %>' Font-Bold="true" Font-Size="Large" Visible="True" />
                                        <br />
                                        <br />
                                        Q<asp:Label ID="PRO_PRECIOLabel" class="card-text" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("PRO_PRECIO") %>' Font-Size="Large" />
                                        <br />
                                        <br />
                                        <div class="input-group">                                            
                                          <asp:Button ID="masInformacion" runat="server" Text="Más Información" class="btn btn-dark m-2" />
                                          <asp:TextBox ID="cantidadComprar" runat="server" type="number" class="form-control m-2" placeholder="Cantidad a Comprar"></asp:TextBox>
                                          <asp:Button ID="agregarCarrito" runat="server" Text="Agregar al Carrito" class="btn btn-success m-2"/ OnClick="agregarCarrito_Click"/>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <br />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:DataList>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al final lo resolví de la siguiente manera:

- Se crea una variable de tipo botón con el ID del botón que ejecuta la acción y el evento "sender" , o sea enviar.
- Se crea un objeto de tipo DataListItem cuando se presiona el evento sender de la variable "boton" o agregarCarrito
- Con el elemento item del datalist, se toma el ID del Textbox y se crea el objeto de tipo textbox (TextBox)
- Se le asigna a una variable string y se convierte a tipo string el resultado

  > //SE OBTIENE EL VALOR SEND DEL BOTON "AGREGAR CARRITO
  > Button agregarCarrito = (Button)sender;
  >
  > ```
  >             //SE CREA UN DATALISTITEM, PARA OBTENER LOS VALORES DENTRO DEL DATALIST
  >             DataListItem item = (DataListItem)agregarCarrito.Parent;
  >
  >             
  >             //SE OBTIENE EL VALOR DEL TEXTBOX "CANTIDADPROD"
  >             TextBox cantidadComprar = (TextBox)item.FindControl("cantidadComprar");
  >             string cantProducto = cantidadComprar.Text.ToString();
  > ```